# Horizontal lines behind buttons HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, button, hyperlink

I am remaking my school's student intranet for an assessment, and I have come across an issue with the buttons. As you can see in the image, there is a horizontal line seen in the gaps between the button links.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VW6u3.png)

Is there any reason this is happening? I have attached the CSS and HTML code for the button section of the website, if it helps.

**CSS:**

```
.button {
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    border:none;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    border-radius:3px;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size:16px;
    cursor:pointer;
    padding:15px;
    z-index:3;
}

.button:hover {
    color:#000000;
    transition:.2s;
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    padding-left:18px;
    padding-right:18px;
}

.button:active {
    color:#000000;
}

.button:focus {
    outline-color:gold;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="links">

    <h2>Links</h2>

        <a href="http://jhclibrary.weebly.com/" alt="JHC Library Website">
            <button class="button">
                Library Website
            </button>
        </a>

        <a href="http://jhclibrary.weebly.com/research.html" alt="Research">
            <button class="button">
                Research
            </button>
        </a>

        <a href="http://jameshargestcollege.wheelers.co/" alt="eBooks">
            <button class="button">
                eBooks
            </button>
        </a>

        <a href="10.0.0.7" alt="Library Catalogue">
            <button class="button">
                Library Catalogue
            </button>
        </a>

        <br><br>

        <a href="http://studentintranet/Documents/SubjectBooklets/ElLink.html" alt="Subject Booklets">
            <button class="button">
                Subject Booklets
            </button>
        </a>

        <a href="http://studentintranet/Documents/Options/ElLink.html" alt="Option Books">
            <button class="button">
                Option Books
            </button>
        </a>



    </div>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line is a continuation of the `<a>` tag from the button code. Changing their `display` property from `inline` (by default) to `inline-block` should fix the issue.

```
.links a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Move `<a>` tag inside `<button>` tag

```
    <div class="links">

    <h2>Links</h2>

    <button class="button">
        <a href="http://jhclibrary.weebly.com/" alt="JHC Library Website">
        Library Website
        </a>
    </button>

    <button class="button">
        <a href="http://jhclibrary.weebly.com/research.html" alt="Research">                    Research
        </a>
    </button>

    <button class="button">
        <a href="http://jameshargestcollege.wheelers.co/" alt="eBooks">
                eBooks
        </a>
    </button>

    <button class="button">
        <a href="10.0.0.7" alt="Library Catalogue">
                Library Catalogue
                </a>
    </button>

    <br>
    <br>

    <button class="button"> <a href="http://studentintranet/Documents/SubjectBooklets/ElLink.html" alt="Subject Booklets">

                Subject Booklets

        </a>
    </button>

    <button class="button">
        <a href="http://studentintranet/Documents/Options/ElLink.html" alt="Option Books">Option Books

        </a>
    </button>

</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f7pabu54/215/)

Comment: I found this helpful, but didn't end up using this solution as I found it required some extra modifications to the buttons via CSS, because it left the text coloured blue and underlined. Thank you very much anyway!